# Identifying another device using CoreBluetooth

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-bluetooth

I'm jut trying to make a sample iOS app that will scan & collect data from a another bluetooth enabled device. Initially I'm just trying to scan a another bluetooth enabled device. So I downloaded a sample from Apple "BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer" app. I'm confused with UUID.  There are two types of UUID I see in the sample app Service and Characteristic. How to get this two different UUID's ? My first mission is two identify a another bluetooth enabled device through my app. Now I'm testing with two iPhone (5 & 4 running iOS 7),trying to scan a another iPhone through my app. It looks quite difficult at the moment. By changing the correct two UUID's Is it possible to scan the another device ? Please provide your suggestion.

Edited :
I have two iPhone for testing 1. iPhone 5 2. iPhone 4 My big concern is Does iPhone 4 has BTLE ? Do both iPhone I test requires BTLE ? 
How to identify a another device and pair it ?

Comment: The iPhone 4 does not have Bluetooth LE. You need at least an iPhone 4s. And you might confuse [Bluetooth Low Energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy) with "regular" or [Classic Bluetooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth).

Comment: So "CoreBluetooth" Framework means its uses BTLE not the regular bluetooth ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. You can't really use Classic Bluetooth inside an app. The only way is to connect to an actual bluetooth device you have developed, you have to be part of the [MFi program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) for this. But you can still only connect to that device, you can't really connect two iPhones with classic bluetooth.

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying BTLE Central Peripheral Transfer sample from Apple using two iPhones (5 & 4) One as central and other as Peripheral but there was no response.

Comment: Can I add "ExternalAccessory" Framework to the project. Is there any possibility that I can run my project in iPhone 4 and act as peripheral ?

Comment: As I said, you can't connect to another iPhone with classic bluetooth. The ExternalAccessory framework can *only* be used to connect to MFi bluetooth hardware (basically hardware that was designed by your company). You can connect two iPhones with Bluetooth LE (and Core Bluetooth). But that won't work with an iPhone 4, because it does not have Bluetooth LE. Get another Bluetooth capable iOS Device (iPhone 4s, iPod Touch 5G, iPad 3, iPad Mini) and the Central and Peripheral example will work.

Comment: Thanks a Lot ! Just now I referred about ExternalAccessory & MFi. Now I'm Clear. How to get a UUID ?

Comment: Yes Finally project worked Good. Later I got a 5S which act as peripheral and 5 as central that's it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking a look at this example on github: https://github.com/liquidx/CoreBluetoothPeripheral/tree/master/CoreBluetoothOSXCentral

If that works for you - try adopting your code. Otherwise, provide code examples that you assume may be problematic

Comment: I tried running iOS sample from the above link. NSLog showed "Powered On" When Bluetooth was enabled in my device but rather there was no response. It wasn't scanning nearby device.